# How can I console $rootScope before each controller in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on debug step. There are several pages. Each time, I would need console the `$rootScope` for debug. I want to know if there is a way to console log the `$rootScope` for all controller? In other words, How can I console `$rootScope` before each controller in angular?

Update:

I mean the statement should run before all controllers without modify the controllers.

Comment: what do you mean by before each controller? you  want to check whether value exists?

Comment: Whole concept doesn't really make sense. What does `debug $rootScope` mean? And what exactly are you needing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular routing, you can use:

```
angular.module('myModule').run([ '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function() {
        console.log($rootScope);
    });
} ]);
```

And if you re using ng-view you can instead listen for `$viewContentLoaded`

Comment: You forgot to inject `$rootScope`

Answer (score 0):

Before execute route change locationChangeStart, still if you want to console it, then you can console or initialize it from main controller first.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'myServices', function ($scope, $rootScope, myServices) {
        $rootScope.test = 'Hello World';
        console.log($rootScope.test);

    }]);
```

Comment: @DotKu : The main controller in your app, will execute first even before If you are using angular routing, so from main controller you can initially declare it and get or update it from anywhere before execute or call any controller.